# How can I see the processing performance details for Snowflake queries within a stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We use stored procedures for most of our processing under Snowflake.

Using the history feature of both the old and new (Snowsight) interfaces, I can see a certain amount of details about the execution of the procedure but I don't seem to see the query plan details...

In particular, I would like to see the number of micro partitions read or pruned, the amount of data read from cache, etc...

Is this possible?

Comment: The individual SQL statements that a stored procedure runs each has its own entry in the query history along with associated query plan and statistics. You can get the session ID of the stored procedure execution and find the statements it ran in the query history.

Comment: I don't see them through the UI even if I login as SYSADMIN and remove the filter on the username. Is it only visible through the views rather than the UI?

Comment: They are there, but may be filtered out due to privileges. A quick way to check if that's the issue is to change the UI role (not the worksheet role, but the one on the top right in the original UI) to ACCOUNTADMIN (or ask someone with that role to check). The statements the SPs are running will show up there.

Comment: I thought I had tried that but I'lll check again. 

Thanks

Comment: @GregPavlik if you enter this as an answer, I'll be able to "accept" it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The individual SQL statements that a stored procedure runs each has its own entry in the query history along with associated query plan and statistics. You can get the session ID of the stored procedure execution and find the statements it ran in the query history

If statements the SP is running do not show up in the Query History page in the UI, it's a privileges issue. In the original UI, the role selected all the way on the top right controls what queries in the History tab a user can see. The ACCOUNTADMIN role can see all queries. Other roles can see the queries run using their role or a child role.

There are two places to set the role in the original UI. One is for the worksheet and sets the role used to run SQL statements. One is on the upper tab strip and sets the role used to perform all non-SQL UI activit; this is the one to set to control what statements are visible in the Query History page.